# In Regression Analysis, should variable transformations occur before or after subset selection?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, feature-selection, data-transformation

I'm looking at fitting a model that has many parameters. In order to simplify the model and prevent overfitting, I am planning to use the best subset selection for variable selection. My question is, should I consider variable transformations before or after I perform variable selection? Why?